# Import multiple Annotations in Pdftron with NodeJs

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdftron

In my application annotations are stored in the database as single annotations. For one document in the document table I store many annotations (multiple xfdf strings) in the annotation table.
I wrote a code to generate the pdf and import these annotations. I referred following links for this code,

- https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/features/forms/import-data/
- https://groups.google.com/g/pdfnet-sdk/c/gXaG5X-zpR8

params,

- annotations : list of annotations with xfdf String
- downloadedFile : pdf file as a buffer
- isFlatternAnnotations - is a boolean option to
  flatten annotations

```
async importAnnotationsToDocument(
    annotations: any,
    downloadedFile: any,
    isFlatternAnnotations: any,
  ) {
    await PDFNet.initialize();
    const pdfDocument = await PDFNet.PDFDoc.createFromBuffer(downloadedFile);
    pdfDocument.lock();

    let fdfDocument = null;
    annotations.forEach(async annotation => {
      fdfDocument = await PDFNet.FDFDoc.createFromXFDF(annotation.xfdfString);
      await pdfDocument.fdfMerge(fdfDocument);
    });

    if (isFlatternAnnotations === 'true') {
      await pdfDocument.flattenAnnotations();
    } 

    const documentBuffer = await pdfDocument.saveMemoryBuffer(
      PDFNet.SDFDoc.SaveOptions.e_remove_unused,
    );
    
    const documentBufferResponse = Buffer.from(documentBuffer);
    PDFNet.shutdown();
    return documentBufferResponse;
}
```

However I noticed the code is working only the `await pdfDocument.flattenAnnotations();` is running. If it is not running annotations are not merged in the document.
And also if it runs a single time, the annotations are displayed without flattening. But if I add the same line three times it works correctly.
I think the way I have done this is not correct. I need your help to write this code correctly.

Following code works correctly, but there should be a proper way to do this.

```
async importAnnotationsToDocument(
    annotations: any,
    downloadedFile: any,
    isFlatternAnnotations: any,
  ) {
    await PDFNet.initialize();
    const pdfDocument = await PDFNet.PDFDoc.createFromBuffer(downloadedFile);
    pdfDocument.lock();

    let fdfDocument = null;
    annotations.forEach(async annotation => {
      fdfDocument = await PDFNet.FDFDoc.createFromXFDF(annotation.xfdfString);
      await pdfDocument.fdfMerge(fdfDocument);
    });

    if (isFlatternAnnotations === 'true') {
      await pdfDocument.flattenAnnotations();
      await pdfDocument.flattenAnnotations();
      await pdfDocument.flattenAnnotations();
    } else {
      // This shows the annotations without flattening 
      await pdfDocument.flattenAnnotations();
    }

    const documentBuffer = await pdfDocument.saveMemoryBuffer(
      PDFNet.SDFDoc.SaveOptions.e_remove_unused,
    );
    
    const documentBufferResponse = Buffer.from(documentBuffer);
    PDFNet.shutdown();
    return documentBufferResponse;
  }
```

Following is the xfdf String for a single annotation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xfdf xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/" xml:space="preserve">
    <fields />
    <add>
        <square page="0" 
            rect="387.88,525.73,525,609.07" 
            color="#FFCD45" flags="print" 
            name="d1aa1a2a-822f-507b-6ff6-d61bcc6bd862" 
            title="test.title" subject="Rectangle" 
            date="D:20210405104448+08'00'" 
            interior-color="#FFCD45" 
            opacity="0.5" 
            creationdate="D:20210405104445+08'00'" />
    </add>
    <modify /><delete />
</xfdf>
```

Comment: There are two types of XFDF files with PDFNet, Regular and Command. You can tell Command ones by looking at the XFDF and seeing if there is <add><modified><delete> top level elements. If that is the format of your XFDF strings, then you use different API's. If those values are present let me know and I can advise further (ideally you can provide example in your question of one of these XFDF strings).

Comment: @Ryan Sorry for the very late reply. I have added the xfdf string.

Comment: Thank you for the update, this confirms you are using the alternate XFDF format. See my new answer on how to apply those server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading a variant of XFDF, called Command, which you can see documented here. https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/xfdf/

The following code is how you would load and apply XFDF command XML data to a `PDFDoc` instance.

```
let fdfDoc = await pdfDoc.fdfExtract(PDFNet.PDFDoc.ExtractFlag.e_both);
await fdfDoc.saveAsXFDF('data.xfdf');
fdfDoc = await PDFNet.FDFDoc.createFromXFDF('data.xfdf');
await fdfDoc.mergeAnnots(str);
await pdfDoc.fdfUpdate(fdfDoc);
await pdfDoc.refreshAnnotAppearances();
```

Comment: @daratha-galkissa Added one additional line of code, to ensure appearances are generated for the annotations.

Comment: This code is working. Thanks you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The API `pdfDocument.flattenAnnotations()` by default only flattens FormFields, and not annotations.
https://www.pdftron.com/api/pdfnet-node/PDFNet.PDFDoc.html#flattenAnnotations__anchor

So I would recommend changing the call to

```
pdfDocument.flattenAnnotations(false);
```